# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when I compose docker container, but app work fine without docker

Tags: python, docker, python-3.7

I am trying to compose a docker image on my local machine in an effort to deploy it to google cloud.

1. The app is simple Python and Flask, built on top of the GPT 2 Repo. So I tried the following commands in terminal:

   $docker build -t text-gen:v1 .

The container and the image are created fine but they exit immediately with code [1]  they don't appear under the running containers when I run `$docker ps` command, however, they do exist under the stoped images when I run `$docker ps -a`

2. I removed the created container using the command `$docker rm text-gen -f`

3- Stoped docker, restarted my mac, started docker again, built a docker compose file and this time I tried the following command to create the container:

`$docker-compose up --build flask`

assuming flask as a service, however, the same thing happened again the containers exits upon creation with code [1].

4. Considering this is my first time using any of these services, it took me a while to find this command 
   `$docker logs text-gen` and it appears there is a syntax error in my main app.py file which doesn't make any sense:

   ```
   (venv) myyapproot $docker logs af6175cxxxx
   ```

   File "app.py", line 89

   ```
       return f'<div>{html}</div>'
                                 ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```

this the code the logs refers to in app.py:

```
87    html = ''
88    html = add_content(html, box(seed, text))
89        return f'<div>{html}</div>'
```

I expected a div element to return some html content, which works fine when I run it in python environment but not in docker
The code seems fine to me, can anyone please point me to the right direction?

I feel Im missing a dependency or something

Things I've done:
-reinstalled Docker with wired connection
-retested my app without docker build several times 
-Used different build method

My setup:
MacOs 10.14.1
Dependencies that produces a working app in python: 
this how I had my environment.yml

```
dependencies:
  - python==3.7
  - pip:
    - Flask==1.0.2
    - torch==1.0.1
    - regex==2017.4.5
    - requests==2.21.0
    - numpy==1.16.2
    - wtforms==2.2.1
    - tqdm==4.31.1
    - gunicorn==19.9.0
    - firebase-admin==2.13.0
    - google-cloud-firestore==0.29.0
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  flask:
    image: text-gen
    build: .
    command: /opt/conda/envs/ml-flask/bin/python app.py
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

and this is my dockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

COPY ["environment.yml", "/root/environment.yml"]

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 ca- 
certificates \
libglib2.0-0 libxext6 libsm6 libxrender1 \
git mercurial subversion python-dev gcc

# install miniconda and python 3.7
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.11- 
Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
/bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
rm ~/miniconda.sh && \
ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda env create -f=/root/environment.yml -n ml-flask
RUN echo "conda activate ml-flask" >> ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.bashrc"]
RUN conda activate ml-flask

COPY ["deployment", "/usr/src/app/deployment"]
COPY ["models", "/usr/src/app/models"]

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/deployment
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

Comment: f-strings have been introduced in Python 3.6, using them with an earlier version causes a syntax error. You should check which version of Python you really run - is it 3.3, as `version: 3.3` at the start of docker-compose.yml suggests?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: I think you are right about the version. The 3.3 is for docker, though, not Python.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille:Its running python 3.7.1 and the version 3.3 is for docker

Comment: I changed the version 3.3 to 3.7. Weirdly enough the syntax error is gone, but now it exits with code [0] and the docker logs returns nothing ... :(

Comment: I know I'm five months late, but I had this same issue - I replaced the f-string format with the older structure "".format() and rebuilt the container, then it ran fine.